# why regular expression match an additional space in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7. And in a long string, I want to match content which starts and ends with `{` `}`. And particularly, I am interested in two parts within `{` `}`. The first part is anything in `[1J, 2J, ..., 10J]` or `[1S, 2S, ..., 10S]`, and wrapped with `()` and delimiter by `,`. The 2nd part I am interested in is the remaining text within `{` `}`.

In the example below, I want to find `(2J,3S)` and `Hello World` in the first `{` `}`, and find `(1J,2S,3J)` and `Hello Python` in the 2nd `{` `}`.

My question is, in my code below, there is an additional space between `J` and `,` in `2J ,3S`, and another additional space between `J` and `,` in `1J ,2S,3J`. Wondering where is the space coming from and how to fix it?

```
import re

judgeItemYesRegNew = r'(\((?:(?:10|[1-9])J|S(?:,|\)))+)(.*?)\s?}'
string = "Some content  {(2J,3S) Hello World } Some content {(1J,2S,3J) Hello Python }"
result = re.findall(judgeItemYesRegNew, string)
for (num, content) in result:
    print num, content
```

Output is,

```
(2J ,3S) Hello World
(1J ,2S,3J) Hello Python
```

Comment: You have `(2J` and `3S) Hello World` captures in the first case. I guess you need to fix the regex. Try `(\([^()]+\))\s*(.*?)\s?}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I think you get the exact point where I am wrong in the code. But what is wrong with my regular expression? I already added a `+` sign there to match more than one as the first capture group.

Comment: The point is that the first part (the first group) only matches the first value before `,` in your input and `.*?` matches the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print num, content` separates the two printed values by a space. Concatenate the two strings if you don't want that space to be printed:

```
print num + content
```

Note that `num` only consists of `'(2J'` and `(1J'`, respectively. The remainder is contained in `content` (`',3S) Hello World'` and `',2S,3J) Hello Python'`, respectively.

That's because you split the group into  a `J` and `S` part with `|`; *everything before and after* within the same parentheses are now part of those two options, not just those two letters. You either match `(?:10|[1-9])J` or you match `S(?:,|\)`.

Use `[JS]` (a character class) instead of alternative grouping:

```
(\((?:(?:10|[1-9])[JS](?:,|\)))+)
```

making the full expression:

```
judgeItemYesRegNew = r'(\((?:(?:10|[1-9])[JS](?:,|\)))+)(.*?)\s?}'
```

This would result in `num = '(2J,3S)'` and `content = '  Hello World'`; note the space, you may want to leave spaces after the closing parens out of the second group:

```
judgeItemYesRegNew = r'(\((?:(?:10|[1-9])[JS](?:,|\)))+)\s*(.*?)\s?}'
```

See https://regex101.com/r/xH5xP9/1 for an online regex demo of the pattern.

Python demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> judgeItemYesRegNew = r'(\((?:(?:10|[1-9])[JS](?:,|\)))+)\s*(.*?)\s?}'
>>> string = "Some content  {(2J,3S) Hello World } Some content {(1J,2S,3J) Hello Python }"
>>> result = re.findall(judgeItemYesRegNew, string)
>>> for (num, content) in result:
...     print (num, content)
...
('(2J,3S)', 'Hello World')
('(1J,2S,3J)', 'Hello Python')
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, tried your code works for me. My question is,  I thought `num` matches `(2J,3S)`, but it seems I am wrong, num only matches `(2J`? Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Wondering what is wrong with my regular expression? I already added a `+` sign there to match more than one as the first capture group.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, mark your reply as answer. Smart catch!

Answer (score 2):

You placed the `+` after your group #1, but you forgot to make sure a comma is also matched. Add it as an optional symbol to match. Also, the `(?:,|\))` part is put inside an alternative branch, while the `)` should be placed outside as the trailing char in Group 1, whule the comma is the one that should be alternated as an optional subpattern.

```
(\((?:,?(?:10|[1-9])[JS])+\))\s*(.*?)\s*}
      ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eH2cJ1/2)

I also modified the pattern to match:

- `(\((?:,?(?:10|[1-9])[JS])+\))` - Group 1:

  - `\(` - a literal `(`
  - `(?:,?(?:10|[1-9])[JS])+` - 1 or more sequences  of:

    - `,?` - an optional comma
    - `(?:10|[1-9])[JS]` - `10` or a single digit followed with either `J` or `S`
  - `\)` - a literal `)`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than a newline up to the first
- `\s*` - 0+ whiotespaces
- `}` - a literal `}`.

And a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/UOVjXk):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(\((?:,?(?:10|[1-9])[JS])+\))\s*(.*?)\s*}')
s = "Some content  {(2J,3S) Hello World } Some content {(1J,2S,3J) Hello Python }"
print(p.findall(s))
```

Comment: Nice catch Wiktor!

Comment: They did *not* forget about the comma. The `[JS]` is much more important, as `J|S` split the group up into parts with and without the comma.

Comment: I added a description of the pattern. Actually, yes, the optional pattern is part of the fix.